# Saving Java Object Graphs as XML file

Tags: java, xml

What's the simplest-to-use techonlogy available to save an arbitrary Java object graph as an XML file (and to be able to rehydrate the objects later)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way here is to serialize the object graph.
Java 1.4 has built in support for serialization as XML.

A solution I have used successfully is XStream (http://x-stream.github.io/)- it's a small library that will easily allow you to serialize and deserialize to and from XML.

The downside is you can only very limited define the resulting XML; which might not be neccessary in your case.

Answer (score 4):

Apache digester is fairly easy: http://commons.apache.org/digester/
JAXB is newer and comes with annotation goodness: https://jaxb.dev.java.net

Answer (score 4):

XStream by the folks at Thoughtworks has a simple API and even deals with things like duplicate and circular references.  It seems to be actively developed and is well documented.

http://x-stream.github.io/

Answer (score 3):

Use `java.beans.XMLEncoder`. Its API is very simple (actually a little too simple; it'd be nice to wire it to a SAX ContentHandler), but it works on many graphs out of the box, and it's easy to create your own persistence delegate for any odd-ball classes you might encounter.

- The syntax used by XMLDecoder allows
  you to invoke any method, instance
  or static, including constructors,
  so it's extremely flexible.
- Other encoders name
  elements and attributes after class
  and field names, so there's no fixed schema for the result. The XMLEncoder's
  XML follows a simple DTD and can
  easily be validated or transformed,
  even when you've never seen the
  types it uses.
- You can assign objects an
  identifier, and reference them
  throughout the graph.
- You can refer to constants defined
  in classes or interfaces.

And, it's built into Java SE, so you don't need to ship an extra library.

Answer (score 3):

## *Simple*

Although XStream and JAXB can serialize an some object graphs succssfully they can not handle very complex graphs. The most powerful solution for large complex graphs is [*Simple* XML Serialization](http://simple.sourceforge.net/). It can handle any graph. Also, it’s fast and simple to use without any dependencies.

To quote the *Simple* project page:

> Simple is a high performance XML serialization and configuration framework for Java. Its goal is to provide an XML framework that enables rapid development of XML configuration and communication systems. This framework aids the development of XML systems with minimal effort and reduced errors. It offers full object serialization and deserialization, maintaining each reference encountered. In essence it is similar to C# XML serialization for the Java platform, but offers additional features for interception and manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

The Simple API is, well, simple! It's really good. http://simple.sourceforge.net/

You can also use XStream: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xstream/index.html

Answer (score 2):

[JAX-B](http://jaxb.java.net/) is part of the standard APIs and really easy to use.

Comment: FYI: [JAXB 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding#Versions) ([JSR 222](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222), [project site](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/), [GitHub](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2)) added the capability to quite simply export a Java object to XML file. Originally JAXB was aimed at going from XML-to-object via [Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema).

Answer (score 2):

If you need control over the XML that gets generated, I recommend taking a look at Betwixt (http://commons.apache.org/betwixt/) - it adds a lot of functionality to Apache's digester (Digester is good for building object graphs from XML, but is not so good for generating them).

If you really don't care about the XML that gets generated (just that it can be deserialized in the future), then the XMLEncoder/Decoder classes built into Java or good - as long as the objects you are serializing follow the JavaBean specification.  The biggest area I've run into problems with the XMLEncoder/Decoder solution is if you have a bean that returns an immutable list for one of it's properties - the encoder doesn't handle that situation very well.

Answer (score 1):

XStream is very simple http://x-stream.github.io/

XStream is a simple library to serialize objects to XML and back again.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to control the structure of the XML, the XStream is a good choice. You can use annotations to define precisely the structure/mapping of the XML and your objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'd second (or third) XStream.  It reads and writes XML without needing any special binding configuration or placing lots of extraneous syntax in the XML.

Answer (score 1):

I [put together a list](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/xml-serializers-for-java/) with a lot of xml serialization libraries and its license

Answer (score 0):

[java.beans.XMLEncoder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

## Jackson

The [*Jackson Project*](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) is a processing and binding library for XML, JSON, and some other formats.

> … Jackson is a suite of data-processing tools for Java (and the JVM platform), including the flagship streaming JSON parser / generator library, matching data-binding library (POJOs to and from JSON) and additional data format modules to process data encoded in Avro, BSON, CBOR, CSV, Smile, (Java) Properties, Protobuf, XML or YAML; and even the large set of data format modules to support data types of widely used data types such as Guava, Joda, PCollections and many, many more…

Answer (score -1):

If you are really only interested in serializing your objects to a file and then deserializing them later, then you might check out YAML instead of XML. YAML is much easier to work with than XML and the output files are very human-readable (which may or may not be a requirement). Check out [yaml.org](http://yaml.org/) for more information. I've used [JYAML](http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/) successfully on a recent project.